# What is the format for Xbox LIVE member profile URLs?

Tags: xbox-network

Previously, the format was http://live.xbox.com/member/`[Gamertag]`, but this is no longer the case.  For example, http://live.xbox.com/member/Xonatron no longer loads.How can I convert old format links to the current format?

EDIT: Also I am looking for the most elegant and clean URL possible, as shown from the previous URL that I used that removed the variable=value format.

Comment: Downvoting because this is relatively easy to discover: clicking on any of your friends' profiles will display the URL pattern in Foxtrot's answer.

Comment: @DaveDuPlantis I think your comment about region codes means it could be hard to find in some cases.  The old link may be on some random website.

Comment: @DaveDuPlantis, you are missing the point of finding an elegant URL, not just *any* URL that works, as the URL I had before.

Comment: With all due respect, I don't believe I'm missing anything. Microsoft is redirecting locale-free URLs to locale-specific URLs, presumably based on the locale associated with your Live profile, which can be verified by removing the locale from the answer below. This isn't a typical change, where the provider would move a page and break links to the old one rather than redirecting you (which is what they should have done, at least for a while, so that your old link would work). If you're aware of locales, testing this yourself would have given you the answer;

Comment: ... and if you weren't aware of locales, then simply clicking on a friend would have given you the answer.

Comment: @DaveDuPlantis, I wasn't just talking about locales... I was also talking about removing the variable=value format, which you can see above that I avoided beforehand. I should have mentioned all this in the question, so it's not your fault.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The format was changed to 'http://live.xbox.com/en-US/Profile?gamertag=[Gamertag]', where '[GamerTag]' is your personal and unique name.

So your example would now be: 'http://live.xbox.com/en-US/Profile?gamertag=Xonatron'.

Comment: Note that the format returns a locale-specific version of the gamertag: replace en-US with the code for your desired locale. For example, fr-CA is Canadian (French); ja-JP is Japanese.

Comment: What about removing the `en-US/` completely, for auto-detection? (That's how we do our links on xona.com.)

Comment: I guess this format doesn't work any more. Redirects on to login page :(

Comment: Yep does not work. I guess MS doesn't want profiles to get spidered and scraped by robots. I don't blame them.

Answer (score 2):

The new format is https://account.xbox.com/en-us/profile?gamertag=`gamertag`.

It still requires a login but after that the format works.

Comment: The old way will still redirect you correctly after you sign in.